# Copy 5th word of the "rich text box1" to "textbox1.text"

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

The `richtextbox1` contains 8 words "The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog". I want to copy the 5th word of the `richtextbox1` to `textbox1.text` when the `button1` clicked.

can this be done using find method such as `find(character, start integer, end integer)` etc ie. finding "empty" (space) character and read the characters until second "empty"(space) character found. or any other better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the split function for this scenario.
e.g

```
textbox1.text = richtextbox1.text.split(" ")(4) 'This is for the 5th word.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the Mid function indeed. Chech it out from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx

Updated

```
textbox1.text = Mid(richtexbox1.text, 1, 5)
```